# Maven build Specification

Tags: java, maven

Using below mentioned command in maven to create a dynamic web module,

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId={packagename} -DartifactId={ProjectName} -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false; 
create Java dynamic web project;
```

By default this creates dynamic web module 2.3 if try to change 3.0 or 3.1 getting an error. How can I change the version or which archetype is create 3.x version by default?

Comment: How are you changing the version to 3.0 or 3.1?  did you just try updating the dependencies version in pom.xml?